# HTML5 range slider input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I try to do simple if/else statements, so for example "If value on slider is 100, append p tag with some text to miles class". I know it is something simple, but I look through the jQuery docs and didn't find the solution for me.

HTML:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="miles"></div>
        <div class="battery-slider">
            <input class="slider-range" type="range" value="0" min="75" max="250" step="25">
            <span class="slider-value">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var rangeSlider = function(){
    var slider = $('.battery-slider'),
    range = $('.slider-range'),
    value = $('.slider-value');
    miles = $('.miles');

    slider.each(function(){
        value.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
            $(this).html(value);
        });
        range.on('input', function(){
            $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
        });
    });

    if ( $(range).val(value) == 100 ) {
        $(miles).append( "<p>Pass</p>" );
    }
    else {
        $(miles).append( "<p>Fail</p>" );
    }
};
rangeSlider();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit unclear, but perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```js
var rangeSlider = function(){
    var slider = $('.battery-slider'),
    range = $('.slider-range'),
    value = $('.slider-value');
    miles = $('.miles');

    slider.each(function(){
      value.each(function(){
          var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
          $(this).html(value);
      });
      range.on('input', function(){
        if ( this.value == 100 ) {
            $(miles).append( "<p>Pass</p>" );
        }
        else {
            $(miles).append( "<p>Fail</p>" );
        }

        $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
      });
    });
};
rangeSlider();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="battery-slider">
        <input class="slider-range" type="range" value="0" min="75" max="250" step="25">
        <span class="slider-value">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="miles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a little bit different thing, I need it to print "Pass" when value on the slider = 100, if it 75 or others print "Fail"

Comment: Is that not what it's already doing? I did edit the snipped just now so as to remove your original non-functioning `if`statement, but that won't alter the sinppet's functionality.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry....I didn't look through your code snippet properly. Thanks a lot, now one more thing. How to make it appear only once if pass or fail?

Comment: Change the `append` calls to `html` calls, e.g. `$(miles).html( "<p>Pass</p>" );`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.